# Zend Framework rewrites: /index gets 404

Tags: apache, zend-framework, routes, http-status-code-404

I have simple rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php
```

Rules work fine on windows server.
On linux (Ubuntu 12.10) they work except `/index` URLs. `/index/*` returns default apache 404 page.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Options -MultiViews` helped.

Problem description: http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3161107.htm

Comment: would you please check my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606329/how-can-remove-public-from-url-using-htaccess-for-localhost-and-host-server (please see update) and please tell me the solution if you solved the same before.