# how can remove '/public' from url using htaccess for localhost and host server?

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework

I'm using zend framework 2 on xampp. I created .htaccess file in the root('htdocs/zendtest/.htaccess') which has the following code,

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} $ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !/zendtest
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /zendtest/public/$1 [R=301,L]
```

my **'zentest/public/.htaccess'** code is,

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

**'zentest/public/index.php'** code:

```
<?php
/**
 * This makes our life easier when dealing with paths. Everything is relative
 * to the application root now.
 */
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));

// Setup autoloading
require 'init_autoloader.php';

// Run the application!
Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php')->run();
```

when I open 'localhost/zendtest' on browser then it takes me to 'localhost/zendtest/public'.I want to remove 'public' from the url by setting htaccess only(which will work both in localhost and online server),without using virtual host.how can I do that ?(theres no 'index.php' file in 'localhost/zendtest/' directory)

-thanks.

***Edit:***

[image]

***Update:***

**directory:**

[image]

I have the following .htaccess (according to Ravi Thapliyal's answer) in the 'zendtest/' folder (theres no 'zendtest/index.php' now in the 'zendtest' folder.just .htaccess. all other folder structures are same as the 'directory' picture.)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /zendtest/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

but it has now the following issue when open 'localhost/zendtest/' on the browser-

[image]

***RESOLVED:***

I had to make some changes like the following picture (the .htaccess was good):

[image]

and achieved the goal-

[image]

Comment: You are using a redirect (`[R]`) instead of an internal rewrite (rule without `[R]`). Please note that the redirect might be cached by your browser, because you used a permanent redirect. This can mess up tests you do.

Comment: I tried "<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./zendtest/index.php [L]

</IfModule>" this too which I successfully used for codeigniter. but codeigniter has 'index.php' in base directory where zend doesn't have that. so this shows the directory structire on the browser. should I create an 'index.php' file there for that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `htdocs/zendtest/.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /zendtest/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

I'm not sure what's `zentest/public/.htaccess` trying to do but the above should rewrite `/zentest` to `/zentest/public` transparently. Now, it's up to your rules in `public/.htaccess` and the `index.php` there.

Comment: I got this error>> "A 404 error occurred
Page not found.

The requested URL could not be matched by routing.
No Exception available". should I create an index file in 'localhost/zendtest' directory for that ?

Comment: Can you try with `public/.htaccess` removed? Do you at least land inside the public directory first?

Comment: got "Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at postmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request." << this error when removed 'public/.htaccess' file.

Comment: With `public/.htaccess` removed, can you access `public/file.php` as `http://site.com/zendtest/file.php` where `file` is any file that actually exists? Once you get this working we would work on your second `.htaccess`.

Comment: ok, it seems now have to make some changes in 'public/.htaccess' or 'public/index.php' cause of the main body of the webpage not found as well as no styles there too.(please see my edit, that picture is without removing the 'public/.htaccess')

Comment: Did you try the way I asked to? What happens with public htaccess is removed and you type /zendtest/index.php?

Comment: I get this error when remove 'public/.htaccess' >> "Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at postmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: You have a typo in your htaccess code (RE`Q`UEST). Please take a look at my answer again.

Comment: I typed exactly same as you did in .htaccess code (that is in the picture,first part). it seems that either 'public/.htaccess' or 'public/index.php' not getting the zend library there thats why got the error like picture which is having the command "<?php echo $this->content; ?>" in 'layout.phtml' file.and also "prependStylesheet($this->basePath() . '/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css')", "prependStylesheet($this->basePath() . '/css/style.css')" , "prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js')" and so on in 'header' of the 'layout.phtml'.

Comment: Do you not see the `Q` missing??

Comment: oh sorry for that, but got the same error page like the picture ('public/.htaccess' removed)

Comment: Place a test.jpg or test.html in `public` now and try to access as `/zendtest/test.html`. If this works, it confirms our redirection is working fine and we need to fix the framework now. Next enable the `public/htaccess` file and note down the error.

Comment: enabling 'public/.htaccess' throws the same error like picture.

Comment: Okay, according to your `public/.htaccess` rules, you're redirecting the URL to `index.php` in the parent directory. I can't comment if that's what zend framework requires to work (as I don't use it) but I can suggest you `htaccess` rules if you tell me which file needs to handle your requests.

Comment: Basically, 500 error was coming due to the typo and 404 because there's no `index.php` in `/zendtest`.

Comment: should I create 'index' in 'zendtest/'?it seems 'public/index.php' not getting the zend library thats why got error like picture which is cause of the command "<?php echo $this->content; ?>" in 'layout.phtml' file.& also "prependStylesheet($this->basePath().'/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css')","prependStylesheet($this->basePath().'/css/style.css')","prependFile($this->basePath().'/js/bootstrap.min.js')" & so on in 'header' of 'layout.phtml'.in the picture(1st part) 'Skeleton Application','Home' &'© 2005-2012 by Zend Technologies Ltd.All rights reserved.'these line come from the 'layout.phtml'

Comment: it seems 'public/index.php' needs to get the zend library and other linked files while the base path is changed. could it be done by changing 'public/.htaccess' code ?

Comment: Can you update the question with your site structure? Exactly where are your framework files stored and the location of static content like css and jpegs.

Comment: I downloaded zend skeleton first then using composer.phar I downloaded and installed zend framework 2. its 2.2 actually.

Comment: Glad to know you got this one sorted. I did actually do some digging into the framework (as a complete newbie :)) and the [official docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html) suggested (skip to the `VirtualHost` part) to actually have `DocumentRoot /path/to/zendtest/public` i.e. the root of a zend project is `public` itself. But, then that was version `1.x` and you've kinda upgraded from `1` to `2.x`. So, I was no where near confident enough to suggest changes to what appears to be a highly custom setup. But, happy to help with your `.htaccess` :)

Comment: VirtualHost isn't any proper solution for stand alone project, .htaccess and changing of the routes can make this a portable system solution :)

Comment: It works but you will need to chnages in module,config.php and layout.phtml as suggested in updation of question.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is setting up myself a local Vhost, which is accessible with Firefox.
To do so I configure the Vhost and manipulate my /etc/hosts file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName p120.local
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot //var/www/tokam_dev/p120/public
        <Directory /var/www/tokam_dev/p120/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
RewriteLog /tmp/p120-rewrite.log
</VirtualHost>
```

To set AllowOverride to All is not really necessary because I could copy the .htaccess content into that Apache vhost-config file but it better emulates the productive environment.