# Codeigniter .htaccess, make public folder as root

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-3

I have this structure of files and folders:

```
framework
-- app
---- cache
---- config
---- controllers
---- models
---- ....
-- system
public
-- assets
---- css
---- js
---- ...
-- uploads
-- .htaccess (2)
.htaccess (1)
```

In the .htaccess nr. 1 i have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
    RewriteRule  ((?s).*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In the .htaccess nr. 2 i have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The problem is:

1. When i access 127.0.0.1 it gives me CI error 404
2. When i access 127.0.0.1/public it display the welcome page

Can u help me a bit with this .htaccess files please?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to follow [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606329/how-can-remove-public-from-url-using-htaccess-for-localhost-and-host-server#answer-19606769).

If not working, you would point your web accessible directory to `public`. I.E. `/var/www/html` make it `/var/www/html/public`.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your root .htc access

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and try changing your controllers filename first letter to capital
so instead of controller, rename it as Controller

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

- .htaccess in the root

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```